# Nhibernate upgrade breaking change on handling null references

Tags: nhibernate

I have recently upgraded from Nhibernate 2.2 to 3.1 and I'm finding there is a breaking change with my code. In the old version if I selected a reference entity that was null I could always read the Id of that refernce as 0. In the new version it appears this has changed so that the reference is now null and I am getting exceptions.

Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. A null reference should have been null always (if anything, I'd consider the "new" behavior a bug fix)

Can you post the relevant code?